# Is there any way I can check the uniqueness of the values in json schema?

Tags: json, validation, json-schema-validator, jsonata

I have a lot of objects with identical fields and I need to check that the people who filled the objects with data did not fill the title and id fields with the same values (these fields should be permanently only with unique values)

The structure of object:

```
ASASFAS:   # id must be unique
    title: 'Name of object'   # title must be unique
    description: 'description'
    event: 'new_event'
```

I don't understand how to implement this using json schema and sonata. I'm new to this.

Comment: Are you looking to **prevent** users from creating objects that would cause duplicates? (That would best solved by your application (checking if input `id` and `title` already exist with your programming language of choice) or with a jsonschema enforcing unique values given to your database collection [as with MongoDB here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/core/schema-validation/) and rejecting inserts that would cause duplicates.) **Or** do you want to **find duplicates in existing** set of objects? (Here JSONata or a JSON processing library in any programming language would do best.)